# Error 2 'If', 'ElseIf', 'Else', 'End If', 'Const', or 'Region' expected

Tags: vb.net

I've made some function that generates an email template. Code it generates is pure HTML with CSS. Problem is compiler does this odd error and highlights each time '#' sign appears which is needed to define colors in CSS. I did try to change '#' to '/pound/' and then string.Replace() on RETURN but no luck. I'm more into C# so there i can escape special characters by using '\' before them but something f$#$ed up there... Once i remove '#' all back to normal and compiles well.
Any guesses ?

btw, i'm using StringBuilder to generate lines of code with sb.Append().

ie.

```
sb.Append("<div style=""color:#333"">some text</div>")
```

Comment: Can you give me a little more context, is this a web application, console app, etc ...

Comment: Is that the exact line of code that you're using in your project? It compiles fine for me. From the error, it sounds like it thinks the pound is a preprocessor directive, which should only happen if the line starts with "#".

Comment: Unable to reproduce.  It definitely sounds like it things your string literal finished immediately before that character, though. And the '#' character is used to define date literals in VB.  But nothing definitive so this is just a comment.

Comment: some context, like the lines of code before and after this, might help determine why the error is occuring.

Comment: JaredPar, it's a web application.

Ryan, this is not an exact line, there are too many things there to write it in here.

Comment: it highlight every place after pound sign, like ccc , ddd , 333 for CSS colours

Comment: You're not trying to put line breaks right before directly in your string literal, are you?

Comment: This is in the aspx.vb file, right? Not hiding in the aspx file itself?

Comment: @eugeneK: Please copy at least five lines for us, the one on which the compiler reports the error, two before and two after that line. It would help us a lot! Also, what IDE are you using?

Comment: I tried this in linqpad and it worked perfectly.  If you were coding in c# you'd already have the answer, dangit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug,

to reproduce it I used VB.NET 2 (VS 2005), I wrote your instruction:

```
sb.Append("<div style=""color:#333"">some text</div>")
```

no problem,

I added some extra `"` to have the error message you got,
I then fixed everything, all errors disappeared except yours.

**Solution**: Delete that line, error disappeared, ctrl-z (undo) --> all ok!

Comment: I replicated it once, quit VS, reloaded, the error didn't reappear and now I can't replicate it anymore.

Comment: I think this is a bug as well. It happened to me while using code on page and writting js tags for scripts as strings. ie. 
<script>js=0</script>

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving this same exact error and was able to simply copy the line, delete the line out, re-add a new line, and paste.